# Dig dual-stack details

Tags: stack, ip, dig

I want to see the ip details of a machine that has a dual-stack. I am using dig to do this using the options -A and -AAAA to get the individual answers, and was wondering if there isn't an option to get both of the results with just one query. Thx

Comment: there has to be a way to get both ipv6 and ipv4 ip adresses in the same query :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get IPv4 and IPv6 with one command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699306/get-ipv4-and-ipv6-with-one-command)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the answer . You have to use the -ANY flag to get both the ipv6 and ipv4 ip's. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is a duplicate question here:

[Get IPv4 and IPv6 with one command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699306/get-ipv4-and-ipv6-with-one-command/32397501#32397501)

Where I've given the alternative answer:

```
dig hostname A hostname AAAA +short
```