# Get IPv4 and IPv6 with one command

Tags: dig

I would like to know if it's possible to get IPv4 and IPv6 addresses with just one invocation of `dig`?

For example, this gives the IPv4 address:

```
dig hostname A
```

And this command will give me the IPv6 address:

```
dig hostname AAAA
```

How can I get both addresses, IPv4 and IPv6, with just one command?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If you're querying an authoritative server for the domain, you can get all the records for a name with an `ANY` query:

```
dig hostname ANY @servername
```

However, this won't work reliably if you're querying a caching server. When a caching server responds to an `ANY` query, it returns whatever records happen to be in cache at the time. If the name has both `A` and `AAAA` records, but the server has only looked up the `A` records recently, the `AAAA` records won't be in the cache, so it won't return them.

Furthermore, there is a proposal to allow DNS servers to refuse to answer `ANY` queries: [Providing Minimal-Sized Responses to DNS Queries that have QTYPE=ANY](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-dnsop-refuse-any/?include_text=1). If you query a server that implements this, you may not be able to get both responses with a single query (although one of the suggestions in that draft is that an `ANY` query might just return all `MX`, `A`, and `AAAA`, since this is often what clients want). So for best reliability, you should just make two queries.

Comment: There's another to way get both address without using dig command?

Comment: You can use the `host` command. By default it does `A`, `AAAA`, and `MX` queries.

Comment: note that `ANY` is discouraged. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-dnsop-refuse-any/?include_text=1 and https://blog.cloudflare.com/deprecating-dns-any-meta-query-type/

Answer (score 102):

It may be that this has been added to dig since the question was asked, but for completeness this can be accomplished through the following query:

```
dig hostname A hostname AAAA +short
```

Source: http://linux.die.net/man/1/dig -- under the 'Multiple Queries' section

Answer (score 8):

Now that IPv6 is a lot more common, I've found myself frequently needing to query both A and AAAA.  I can never seem to remember the syntax, so I finally wrote a function for my `~/.bashrc` called `digall`.  I shared it with some friends and they loved it, so I threw it up on github in gist that anyone is welcome to use:  https://gist.github.com/FreedomBen/23020c464779bb30cab754d92bdce6c6

Here's the current version which you can put in a file in your path and mark executable:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#
# To use, simply run `digall <domain>` such as:
#
#   digall example.com
#   digall sub.example.com
#
# Place this file in your PATH.  Suggest either /usr/local/bin/ or ~/bin
#
# Alternatively you can wrap it in a function called `digall` and put in ~/.bashrc
#

# License:  MIT

declare -rx digall_color_restore='\033[0m'
declare -rx digall_color_red='\033[0;31m'
declare -rx digall_color_light_green='\033[1;32m'
declare -rx digall_color_light_blue='\033[1;34m'
declare -rx digall_color_light_cyan='\033[1;36m'

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
  echo -e "${digall_color_red}Error: Please pass domain as first arg${digall_color_restore}"
else
  echo -e "${digall_color_light_blue}Queries: (dig +noall +answer '$1' '<type>')...${digall_color_light_cyan}\n"

  for t in SOA NS SPF TXT MX AAAA A; do
    echo -e "${digall_color_light_green}Querying for $t records...${digall_color_restore}${digall_color_light_cyan}"
    dig +noall +answer "$1" "${t}"
    echo -e "${digall_color_restore}"
  done
fi
```