# Query IPv4 and IPv6 with DNS pipelining

Tags: dns

**Background**

We have seen some DNS [servers](https://docs.infoblox.com/display/NAG8/Enabling+Multiple+DNS+Requests+through+a+Single+TCP+Session) block the queries where both ipv4 and ipv6 are queries together from DNS in a single TCP command

The [RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7766#section-7) says this is something called DNS pipelining, [6.2.1.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7766#section-6.2.1.1)

[image]

**Query**

I am trying to understand how to simulate this from the command line or C code.

I came across this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699306/get-ipv4-and-ipv6-with-one-command) but it doesn't issue a single query rather 2 queries one after the other. That is not what I need

Basically I need a way to issue such queries at will to prove to the customer that their DNS is at fault :)

Any pointers how to achieve this ? I am wondering how glibc/resolver is doing it. Tried digging there but could not figure out

Can someone point me to some code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for: https://manpages.debian.org/experimental/bind-dnsutils/mdig.1.en.html

> mdig is a multiple/pipelined query version of dig: instead of waiting
> for a response after sending each query, it begins by sending all
> queries. Responses are displayed in the order in which they are
> received, not in the order the corresponding queries were sent.

Comment: Yup !! Seems to do the trick. Thanks much